# Can I add versions to YAML Swagger objects?

Tags: object, properties, swagger, versioning

I am creating a API definition, and a I wanto to split my  canonical model to different documents and use the JSON pointer '$ref' to reuse them. 
      I need to find a way to add version in the YAML files. 
 For instance:

```
***pj.yaml***
 pJType:
  verison: 1.0
  type: object
  properties:
    cnpj:
      type: integer

***afastamento.yaml***
oswagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: AfastamentoService
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  '/{nis}':
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: nis
          type: integer
          required: true

      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/pesquisarResponse'
definitions:
  pesquisarResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      listaAfastamento:
        $ref: '#/definitions/listaAfastamentoType'
  ...
  empregadorType:
    type: object
    properties:
      personalidadeJuridica:
        type: string
      pessoaJuridica:
        $ref: pJ.yaml#/pessoaJuridicaType
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the extension properties (prefixed with `x-`) to add arbitrary data to the spec:

```yaml
# pj.yaml
pJType:
  x-version: 1.0

  type: object
  properties:
    cnpj:
      type: integer
```